# oracle join the same table but with diffferent date

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, full-outer-join

I have a simple table that contain two columns Cust_Id and Sales:

```
custID_1| sales_1 |sales_date_1| 
01      | 100     |01/2021     | 
02      | 102     |02/2021     | 
07      | 10      |04/2021     | 
10      | 180     |05/2021     | 
12      | 90      |06/2021     | 



custID_2| sales_2 |sales_date_2| 
05      | 400     |02/2022     | 
06      | 110     |03/2022     | 
08      | 300     |04/2022     | 
11      | 80      |06/2022     |
```

and I want to show the result at once in two different dates like below:

```
custID_1| custID_2 |sales_1 |sales_2 |sales_date_1|sales_date_2
01      | null     |100     |null    |01/2021     |null    
02      | 05       |102     |400     |02/2021     |02/2022
null    | 06       |null    |110     |null        |03/2022
07      | 08       |10      |300     |04/2021     |04/2022  
10      | null     |180     |null    |05/2021     |null        
12      | 11       |190     |80      |06/2021     |06/2022
```

here is what I tried below but I get duplicated value:

```
Select S1.Cust_Id "custID_1", s2.Cust_Id "custID_2",
s1.Sales "sales_1", s2.Sales "sales_2",
s1.Sale_Date "sales_date_1", s2.Sale_Date "sales_date_2"
From Sales_Table S1 Left Join Sales_Table S2
On S1.Cust_Id = S2.Cust_Id
And S1.Sale_Date Between '01-01-21' And '31-10-21'
And S2.Sale_Date Between '01-01-22' And '31-10-22'
```

Comment: Maybe it would help if you also posted the source table; we have your query (which, as you said, isn't working) and desired result. But, what's the source?

Comment: You need full outer join on sales_date.

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS This is a faq. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search reasonably.

Answer (score 0):

The dates in your sample data are confusing, but I guess that you want to join both tables on the same date on different years.

Assuming, of course, that your dates are stored as a `date`-like datatype, you can `full join` and use date arithmetics:

```
select s1.cust_id cust_id_1, cust_id_2, 
    s1.sales sales_1, s2.sales sales_2,
    s1.sale_date sale_date_1, s2.sale_date sales_date_2
from (
    select * 
    from sales_table 
    where sale_date >= date '2021-01-01' and sale_date < '2022-01-01'
) s1
full join (
    select * 
    from sales_table 
    where sale_date >= date '2022-01-01' and sale_date < '2023-01-01'
) s2 on s2.sale_date = s1.sale_date + interval '1' year
```

Notes:

- this only works if there is at most 1 sale per date in each table ; otherwise, rows would end up "multiplied" in the resultset
- I pre-filtered the tables ; but if each table has data for one year only, then this step is not needed